# loading external url with jquery ui modal

Tags: jquery

This question was asked before but it was left unanswered.

I have links to comments as read comments, I have read comments, I have read comments...

How can I load external URL into my modal dialogs?

FYI, I want to use it for comments left on each post on the website. So I want multiple URLs loaded (not at the same time) onClick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can load external url via jquery [`Load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/). 
This method is the simplest way to fetch data from the server. It is roughly equivalent to $.get(url, data, success) except that it is a method rather than global function and it has an implicit callback function. When a successful response is detected (i.e. when textStatus is "success" or "notmodified"), .load() sets the HTML contents of the matched element to the returned data. This means that most uses of the method can be quite simple:

```
$('#result').load('ajax/test.html', function(data) {
  // dosome thing with your call back function
});
```

dialog box

```
$('#dialog').dialog({
open:function(){
    //append the html from load();
}
});
```

Comment: I guess I couldnt explain it clearly before. I have links to comments as <a href="comment.php?postid=1>read comments</a>, I have <a href="comment.php?postid=2>read comments</a>... I have hundreds of posts on my website and users keep adding them so I need something that will only work with OnClick and will not pre-load anything.